# Round BigDecimal to match C++ sprintf

Tags: java, c++, rounding, bigdecimal

I am migrating a C++ app to Java. How can I match the rounding behaviour of sprintf?

```
int main() {
    char result[20];
    double dArr [6] = {5.05, 5.15, 5.25, 5.35, 5.45, 5.55};

    for(int i; i< 6; i++) {
        sprintf(result,"%3.1lf",dArr[i]);
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


VALUE      C++ sprintf Rounding: 
---------  ----------------------------------------
5.05    -   5.0 (rounding: half_down or half_even?)
5.15    -   5.2 (rounding: half_up   or half_even?)
5.25    -   5.2 (rounding: half_down or half_even?)
5.35    -   5.3 (rounding: half_down or half_odd ?)
5.45    -   5.5 (rounding: half_up   or half_odd ?)
5.55    -   5.5 (rounding: half_down or half_odd ?)
```

**UPDATE:**
Max Zoom Thank you. Your test works perfect.

But In my code I get the values from DB defined as:

```
@Column(precision=3, scale=2) //Oracle: CLASSAVERAGE NUMBER(3,2)
private BigDecimal classaverage;
```

And when I try to round the number to BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN:

```
System.out.println(getClassaverage() + " - " + getClassaverage().setScale(1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN) );
```

I get value `"5.55" rounded to "5.6".`

After I modified your test, I see why it's happening:

```
@Test
public void main() {
   double [] dArr = {5.05, 5.15, 5.25, 5.35, 5.45, 5.55};
   for (double d : dArr) {
      System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d) + " - " + new BigDecimal(d).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
   }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
5.04999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 - 5.0
5.1500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625 - 5.2
5.25 - 5.2
5.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 - 5.3
5.45000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125 - 5.5
5.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 - 5.5
```

When I replaced the `double[]` to `String[]`, your test produces expected values for `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN`:

```
5.05 - 5.0
5.15 - 5.2
5.25 - 5.2
5.35 - 5.4
5.45 - 5.4
5.55 - 5.6
```

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to use your own rounding:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecimalFormat
{
   private static int ROUNDING_MODE = BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN;
   private static int DECIMALS = 1;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      double[] dArr = {5.05, 5.15, 5.25, 5.35, 5.45, 5.55};
      for (double d : dArr)
        System.out.println(rounded(new BigDecimal(d)));
  }   

   public static BigDecimal rounded(BigDecimal number){
    return number.setScale(DECIMALS, ROUNDING_MODE);
  }
}
```

It looks like you want to format a currency number:

```
public static String currencyFormat(BigDecimal n) {
  return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(n);
}
```

Comment: I voted for your answer, after reviewing my own. ;-)

Comment: Thank you a lot.  My understanding that ROUND_HALF_EVEN should round to the closest even number. Therefore, rounded(5.35) == 5.4; && rounded(5.45) == 5.4

Comment: Basically the difference is between:  BigDecimal(5.55) == 5.49999999... which rounds to 5.5;  And  BigDecimal("5.55") == 5.55 and rounds to 5.6

Comment: How do you like Java classes compering to C++?

Comment: java 100 times easier & cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I have removed my solution as it was wrong. But I will put an explanation for the not so obvious behaviour of the C++ rounding.

using this C++ code reveal the internal value of the doubles.

```
int main() {
    char result[20];
    double dArr [6] = {5.05, 5.15, 5.25, 5.35, 5.45, 5.55};
    for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++) {
        sprintf(result, "%3.16f  %3.1lf", dArr[i], dArr[i]);
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result shows that the rounding is always half up.

```
5.0499999999999998  5.0
5.1500000000000004  5.2
5.2500000000000000  5.3
5.3499999999999996  5.3
5.4500000000000002  5.5
5.5499999999999998  5.5
```

My initial suggestion amended

```
double[] dArr = {5.05, 5.15, 5.25, 5.35, 5.45, 5.55};
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.0");
for (double d : dArr) {
    System.out.printf("%.16f %s%n", d, df.format(d));
}
```

Shows that in Java the given double values are precice and the rounding mode is also half to even.

```
5.0500000000000000 5.0
5.1500000000000000 5.2
5.2500000000000000 5.2
5.3500000000000000 5.4
5.4500000000000000 5.4
5.5500000000000000 5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent in Java:

```
System.out.printf("%3.1f", 5.05); // 5.1
```

Comment: The conversion will be done always with "round half up" see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", insertFloatValueHere);
```

automatically rounds to the nearest tenth

if you want to change the number of decimal places it rounds to:

`"%.1f"` rounds to one place
`"%.2f"` rounds to two places
`"%.3f"` rounds to three places... etc.

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", dArr[i]);
```

replaces:

```
sprintf(result,"%3.1lf",dArr[i]);
cout << result << endl;
```

Comment: The question clearly mentions `BigDecimal.` You don't.

Comment: @EJP I would assume once you know how to do this, you would know how to do it with big decimal

Comment: The conversion will be done always with "round half up" see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html